# Как вызвать родительскую функцию в Битриксе?

Tags: php, битрикс

Создаю свой класс, в котором хочу наследовать класс СUser и один из его методов.

```
    abstract class MineClass extends CAllUser {
public static function GetByID($ID){
   parent::GetByID($ID);
}
}
```

Но вызвать его не могу

```
    $htmm = MineClass::GetByID($_SESSION['SESS_AUTH']['USER_ID']);
```

Comment: Потому что абстрактный класс.

Comment: я пока не очень в php, можете подсказать какой-выход из ситуации, и в чем собственно загвоздка?
Я думал в абстр. классах нельзя создавать объекстов, а я ведь просто обращаюсь к нему. Или же я таким способом косвенно пытаюсь создать объект?

Comment: Просто уберите слово abstract, а потом займитесь чтением документации. Рано вам битрикс.

Comment: к сожалению нужно абстракт.
Я так понимаю, чтобы вызвать этот класс мне нужно будет еще раз его унаследовать и из него уже получать эту функцию, верно?

Comment: не при делах тут абстрактность класса. метод статический, у вот у родителя может быть и не статический

Comment: что за ошибка то там у вас?

Comment: Я потом Fetch() применяю и получаю "[Error] 
Call to a member function Fetch() on null (0)"

Comment: Статический у родителя.
А если я вызываю напрямую: $htmm = MineClass::GetByID($_SESSION['SESS_AUTH']['USER_ID']);
но в своем классе поменя название функции, то вызываеться все окей

Comment: расширьте свой вопрос кодом, где работает, а где нет. Добавьте описание ошибки. Сами пишете, что ошибка при `Fetch()`, тогда при чем тут `GetByID()`. Вернул вам этот метод `null`, не найдя пользователя, а вы потом вызываете `fetch()`, получая ошибку.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52597/discussion-between--and-teran).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема сводится к тому, что родительский метод [`GetByID()`](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/main/reference/cuser/getbyid.php) возвращает объект пользователя. Однако в классе-наследнике метод вызывается, однако, результат не возвращается из метода. Таким образом добавление инструкции `return` решит проблему.

```
public static function GetByID($ID){
    return parent::GetByID($ID);
}
```